# Invocable method with wrapper parameter in console

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, class, invocable-method, invocablevariable

I have invocable method and trying to  pass wrapper as parameter. But i wanna run that in console. How can i do it? It gives me error  wrong parameter  when i am trying to pass Wrapper Object.

```
public class InvokeApexFromFlowController{
    
    @InvocableMethod(label='Invoke Apex')
    public static List<FlowOutputs> invokeThisMetho(List<FlowInputs> request) {
        List<FlowOutputs> results = new List<FlowOutputs>();
        return results;
    }        
    public class FlowInputs{
    
        @InvocableVariable
        public Account accountSobj;
        
        @InvocableVariable
        public String nameToBeUpdate;
        
    }
    
    public class FlowOutputs{
        
        @InvocableVariable
        public String accountPreviousName;
        
        @InvocableVariable
        public String DMLResult;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post to include the error message *verbatim*. If you are running an anonymous script and hitting the aforementioned error, you should include that script also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a List of wrapper objects.

```
List<InvokeApexFromFlowController.FlowInputs> values = new List<InvokeApexFromFlowController.FlowInputs>();
InvokeApexFromFlowController.FlowInputs value = new InvokeApexFromFlowController.FlowInputs();
value.accountPreviousName = 'whatever';
value.DMLResult = 'whatever';
values.add(value);
```

Now, just pass in `values` for the flow parameters.

Comment: Works perfect, thanks.